# Subject Auxiliary Inversion and the usage of 'ever' and 'never'

Tags: articles, subject-auxiliary-inversion

Please let me know if the following sentences is correct:

> 1- Have you never tried the Doritos Wasabi flavor?

My question is related to using 'have' with 'never'. I've seen the present perfect with 'ever'. If I say:

> 2- Have you ever tried the Doritos Wasabi flavor?

Do both of the questions have the same meaning? If so, then why do I feel like I'm presuming in the first sentence that the person has never tried that particular flavor of Doritos in his/her life. Is using 'ever' or 'never' interchangeable in this case?

Another question I have is about using the 'the' before 'Doritos'. Is it fine to use the definite article because I'm mentioning one of the flavors of Doritos?

Look forward to getting your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct, but have somewhat different meanings. You are correct that the first sentence presumes that the person has never tried that flavor of Doritos; in fact, most typically this question expresses a bit of surprise that this is the case.

More typical, though, would be to simply use the statement and ask it as a question:

> *You:* I have never tried Wasabi Doritos.
>   *Me:* You've never tried Wasabi Doritos? You don't know what you're missing.

You might use the question as you have it in this sort of context:

> Someone mentioned that you have never tried Wasabi Doritos. Have you really never tried them?

If you just ask the question as you have it, some sort of context like that would be understood.

Finally, if I ask you if you have *ever* tried them, I am conveying that I have no idea whether you have tried them or not.